# Define polygons with structured data points

Tags: polygon-creation, matlab

I am doing image processing and I get some scatter points (blue) now, filled with random points (red) on it.[image]

I want to find the random points lay inside scatter blue circles. So I tired  with MATLAB but cannot do it successfully, as shows.

So my idea is first define all the polygons based on scatter points (hand-draw with black), then use  algorithm. Now I just cannot find a way to define these black polygons.[image] Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer but just an idea, You can use raster analysis on your blue points convert to raster (with fine pixel size), then use an edge enhancement filter that would depict the edges of blue, convert that to lines, clean it a bit then build your polygons form lines. latter you can easily select red points contained by the polygons.